OnPlatform control of type x:Double is not accessible as font size
I defined an OnPlatform style of type x:Double in my main Styles.xaml which I want to use for defining different font sizes per platform. The problem is when I want to call the resource via the specified x:Key the font size of the label does not change.
My Styles.xaml file:
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ClientApp.Source.Controls"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ClientApp.Source.Views">

    <OnPlatform x:Key="TinyFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="Default" Value="12" />
    </OnPlatform>
...

In a ContentPage I created following label:
...
<Label FontSize="{StaticResource TinyFontSize}" Text="Test" WidthRequest="200"/>
...

but the font size of the label does not change to size 12, only when I replace {StaticResource TinyFontSize} with a numeric value.
When I create following resource in the Styles.xaml file:
<x:Double x:Key="SmallFontSize">13</x:Double>

it would work fine but then I can not change the value depending on the operating system from the main Styles.xaml.
I found an example on Github in the eShop repository:
https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/ClientApp/Views/CheckoutView.xaml.
But even when I checkout this project and run the ClientApp it does not work...
Using:
net8.0
Microsoft.Maui.Controls (8.0.21)

The official documentation states that The OnPlatform class defines a Default property that can be set to a value that will be applied to all platforms.
But I found through testing that when <On Platform="Default">, on the three platforms of Android, iOS and Windows Setting the font size doesn't work either.  You can post this issue to MAUI Github.
When I set the code: <On Platform="Andorid"> and <On Platform="iOS">, I can successfully change the font size on the Android platform and iOS platform respectively.
So as a workaround, if you just run your MAUI program on Android and iOS platforms, you can design the code of styles.xaml as:
<ResourceDictionary 
...>

<OnPlatform x:Key="TinyFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="12" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="12" />
</OnPlatform>
...

